# Get row index in datagridview on selecting the row and pressing enter

Tags: c#

When I select the first row, I'm getting the row index as 1 which must be 0 if I'm not wrong, and 2 on selecting both 2nd and 3rd row.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        r = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    }
}


private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        p = p+1;
        if (p == 1)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                brand = dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                datadisp();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add tags your question is about next time, like [WPF]

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to perform main operation on Enter key press then you don's need to store selected row index in `r` on `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` event. You can access the selected rows in keypress event. So remove `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` and update your code for `dataGridView1_KeyPress` as below.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        p = p+1;
        if (p == 1)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                brand = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                datadisp();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when the 1st row is selected its taking the value of 2nd row..n when 2nd row is selected its taking 3rd row n so on..